# Javascript Regex, need to allow the user to select only word(s)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a paragraph, in the text, user only need to select the valid text. they should not select just a `space` or nay special charector. so user can select a valid text or number. for that i am trying using `regex` like this

```
\b(.+)\b
```

But not working. as a paragrap, i would like to avoid selecting meaning less.

Any one help me?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use character class of digits and alphabets along with ignoreCase flag. `.+` will match any character. You could use `\w+` but it also includes `_`, which is why a character class is used.

```
/[a-z\d]+/i
```

Answer (score 0):

> so user can select a valid text or number

```
\w+
```

`\w` matches any word character.

OR

```
[^\W_]+
```

Comment: But we can just select a `_` it is meaning less.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow your users to select more than one words, try the following:

```
(\w+\s+)*\w+
```